# Ektron - using an iPad to edit content

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

We are on version 8.5 SP3 of the Ektron CMS.  Can my content editors use an iPad/iPhone to edit content and expect the CMS to behave as if on a PC?  It was my impression that the CMS in this version is not supported on mobile devices.  Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not officially supported. Authoring in Ektron isn't supported for mobile browsers or devices (as you can find the OS requirements on the [Ektron Documentation page](http://www.ektron.com/Documentation/8-5-System-Requirements/)), at least not at this time.

I have had limited success on 8.6+ with in-context editing. But I only ever attempted minor text changes. I wouldn't expect anything much more advanced to work.